# how to enable textbox based on some choice

Tags: jquery, html

Enabling `txtEmployer` only when Employment type is contract or full time, should be deactivated for Full time.

```
<div>
  <select id="SelectEmployment">
    <option value="Select Employment">Employment Type</option>
    <option value="Full-time">Full-time</option>
    <option value="Part-time">Part-time</option>
    <option value="Contract">Contract</option>
    <option value="Fixed term">Fixed term</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" id="txtEmployer" value="Employer" class="txtinline water"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you spent ANY time googling this?

Comment: textbox should be deactivated or activated for full time???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is ambiguous about full-time.So, i have assumed first one as Part-time. Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#SelectEmployment').change(function(){
        if($(this).val() == 'Contract' || $(this).val() == 'Part-time') {
            $('#txtEmployer').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
        if($(this).val() == 'Full-time') {
            $('#txtEmployer').attr('disabled', true);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
$("#SelectEmployment").change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "Fixed term") {
        $('#txtEmployer').attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
    else {
        $('#txtEmployer').removeAttr("disabled");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :

```
$("#SelectEmployment").change(function () {
    if ($(":selected", $(this)).text() == "Contract" || $(":selected", $(this)).text() == "Full-time") {
        $("#txtEmployer").removeAttr("disabled");
    } else {
        $("#txtEmployer").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
function updateState(val){
    $('#txtEmployer').prop('disabled', !(val == 'Full-time' || val == 'Contract'));
}

$('#SelectEmployment').change(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    updateState(val);
});

updateState($('#SelectEmployment').val());
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ZZGBj/)